# get the latest files (more than 1) from dir

Tags: python, pandas, glob

i'm trying to extract the latest 'apple','pear' and other .csv stored in a directory in python. The new files get stored with the same prefix but with different frequency (e.g, apple_gets an update every 5 days or so).  Looking at something like `latestfile = max(filenames, key=os.path.getctime)` but category `.startwith`? specific - so i'd pull the only melon_ csv if there is one even though it was saved months ago.

```
    """
fileDir contains csv files such as:

pear_20171102_report2.csv
apple_20171027_report2.csv
orange_20171101_report2.csv
kiwi 20171102 report2.csv
pear_20171101_report2.csv
cherry 20171101 report2.csv
kiwi 20171101 report2.csv
cherry 20171031_report2.csv
mango 20171001 report2.csv
apple_20171101_report2.csv
apple_20171102_report2.csv
...
"""

import glob
import os
import re

fileDir = r'\\ac2knyc05\TestData/'

filenames = glob.glob(fileDir+'*')
regex = re.compile(r'\d{8}')
dates = []
prefix = []

for filename in filenames:
    try:
        date = regex.search(filename).group()
        dates.append(date)
        prefix.append(filename.split(date)[0])

    except AttributeError:
        print(filename)

latestfile = max(filenames, key=os.path.getctime)

print(set(prefix))
```

stuck here, not sure how to proceed, maybe pandas?

Comment: Are these filenames placed inside another file? You need to be more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: what is the input & the expected output? it's not clear what you want

Answer (score 2):

No need for pandas, you can use [itertools groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

def key(filename):
    return filename.replace(" ", "_").split("_")[0]

{k: max(g, key=os.path.getctime)
     for k, g in groupby(sorted(filenames, key=key), key)}
```

while get you a dictionary of category to the latest file.

---

Note: You can get this in a single pass with a for loop:

```
res = {}
for f in filenames:
    k, t = key(f), os.path.getctime(f)
    if k not in res:
        res[k] = f, t
    else:
        _, t_ = res[k]
        if t > t_:
            res[k] = f, t

[f for f, _ in res.values()]  # list of the latest file for each category
```

Comment: @EricDuminil good point, also added way to do in a single pass.

Answer (score 1):

No need for pandas. You could simply put those filenames in a dict of lists:

```
filenames = """pear_20171102_report2.csv
apple_20171027_report2.csv
orange_20171101_report2.csv
kiwi 20171102 report2.csv
pear_20171101_report2.csv
cherry 20171101 report2.csv
kiwi 20171101 report2.csv
cherry 20171031_report2.csv
mango 20171001 report2.csv
apple_20171101_report2.csv
apple_20171102_report2.csv"""

categories = {}
for filename in filenames.split("\n"):
    start_with = filename.split(' ')[0].split('_')[0]
    categories.setdefault(start_with, []).append(filename)

print(categories)
# {'pear': ['pear_20171102_report2.csv', 'pear_20171101_report2.csv'], 'apple': ['apple_20171027_report2.csv', 'apple_20171101_report2.csv', 'apple_20171102_report2.csv'], 'orange': ['orange_20171101_report2.csv'], 'kiwi': ['kiwi 20171102 report2.csv', 'kiwi 20171101 report2.csv'], 'cherry': ['cherry 20171101 report2.csv', 'cherry 20171031_report2.csv'], 'mango': ['mango 20171001 report2.csv']}
```

For each category, you now have list which you can sort by `ctime`.

Comment: @Vrun: Sure you can.

Comment: thanks.  filenames.split("\n"):  does not seem to work  as my filenames from glob is a list of paths while you assigning to a string

Comment: @Vrun: Indeed, that was just an example on how to initialize `filenames` without having to create a fake directory.